# Eclipse deleting project but not the source code

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is there a way to **delete** an Eclipse project while preserving all the resources? (i.e. source code, etc.).

I guess I could delete the following files from the project directory manually:

```
.cproject
.project
```

But I am concerned that my Eclipse `.metadata` information that lives in my `workspace` may still look for those files and get confused if I delete the project files manually.

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve? "Remove the project from Eclipse" means "remove from project explorer"?

Comment: @shkschneider Yes, I would like remove all the Eclipse-related information about the project. Ultimately, I would like to re-create the project from scratch. Sometimes my **index** for my project stops working, and I noticed that rebuilding/refreshing the index or cleaning and rebuilding the binaries doesn't fix it. In those cases, I found that re-creating the project from scratch helps, but if I click on "delete project" it also deletes my source code (in the past I fixed this by restoring my source code  from my git repository, but it would be easier if Eclipse does not delete the src code)

Comment: Eclipse proposes to remove sources when you remove a project. Uncheck this. Also `ls -lA /your/project/path` should tell you what files to remove.

Comment: Thanks @shkschneider. The only question I get is `Delete project contents on disk (cannot be undone)?`. Is that asking to delete the project information while preserving the source code? It looks as if it would just delete the project info from the workspace, but maybe keep `.cproject` and `.project` in disk.

Comment: Yeah. What I usually do is remove using eclipse (do NOT delete project contents on disk) and remove any .* eclipse-related file that could stay. It worked for what I wanted, but it's maybe not what you want, so I post this as a comment :)

Comment: @shkschneider That actually worked for me. If you write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is remove the project using eclipse (do **not** delete project contents on disk) and remove any .* eclipse-related file that could stay.

[image: eclipse-delete-project]

With the checkout **unchecked**, it deletes the project informations while preserving the source code.